# C++ Access Oracle in Linux

Tags: c++, oracle

My requirements are as following which is nothing special:

1. C++ in Linux(CentOS 6), Oracle 11i
2. Multi-threaded
3. Prefer stored procedure as it means a bit faster due to
           'precompile'.
4. Read/write C++ struct with primitives only

I knew lots of libs are there such as Pro*C, sqlapi++, unixodbc. Can anyone share certain clean sample code for me to get started?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to be portable between database, just use occi.
see [Oracle C++ OCI Database Example](http://www.tidytutorials.com/2009/08/oracle-c-occi-database-example.html)

Comment: Probably it is blocked in my region..Do you mind sending off the web page to me if you have one moment? thanks. (mail: bill.z.li AT gmail)